# Silverlight Plugin Crashes in Chrome

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, silverlight-plugin

When using Silverlight 5 in Chrome, if the code opens in a popup window that also contains Silverlight application, then the Silverlight plugin get crashed why?

Answer (score 0):

There is similar bug in MS Connect (not fixed)  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/726815/silverlight-4-and-5-plugin-crashes